# Initializing Array in Excel VBA - getting error

Tags: excel, vba

In the microsoft site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wak0wfyt.aspx#BKMK_DeclaringAnArray

It says I can initialize an array like this:

```
Dim doubles = {1.5, 2, 9.9, 18}
```

But I'm getting error:

```
Compile error: Expected: end of statement
```

And it points to the equals sign. I'm merely copy-pasting, what's wrong here?

Comment: you haven't followed the syntax which is clearly stated at the link you gave. sigh...

Comment: you do realise that VBA is not VB.NET, right?

Comment: Oops, no. I don't know that. I thought VBA and VB and VB.NET are all same. Maybe you can help me how to do this in Excel VBA? I'm doing this in Excel Macro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would work in vb or vb.net but not vba. You need to initialise this in two steps.

```
Dim doubles
doubles = array(1.5, 2, 9.9, 18)
```